# Change preferred applications in GNOME 3 fallback

Tags: configuration, gnome

I can't find out how to change my preferred application since I'm using GNOME 3 fallback (two panel style) in Oneiric.

Answer (score 2):

I was wondering this myself and I eventually found it on a tab called <kbd>Default Applications</kbd> in the <kbd>System Info</kbd> Utility.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your System Settings, then click the System Info icon. Finally, choose Default Applications in the left menu.

[image]